# For $(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ positive semi-definite, and $(b_{ij})_{n\times n}$ symmetric, show $\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^{n}a_{il}a_{kj}b_{ij}b_{kl}\geq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\left(a_{ij}\right)_{n\times n}$ be a (real) positive semi-definite matrix 
>   and $\left(b_{ij}\right)_{n\times n}$ be a (real) symmetric matrix.
>   Prove that 
>   $$
> \sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^{n}a_{il}a_{kj}b_{ij}b_{kl}\geq0.
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum can be rewritten as $\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)\ge0$. By the tracial property, we have $\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)=\operatorname{tr}(A^{1/2}BABA^{1/2})=\operatorname{tr}((A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^2)$. Since $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is symmetric, its square is positive semidefinite and has a nonnegative trace. Hence the result.

Comment: That's incredible.